# stop countdown when reaches 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hello i want to stop my decrement function when second reach 0 see code bellow the problem is when second reach 0 the countdown function still work

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    // set minutes
    var mins = 5;
     
    // calculate the seconds (don't change this! unless time progresses at a different speed for you...)
    var secs = mins * 60;
    function countdown() {
     setTimeout('Decrement()',1000);
    }
    function Decrement() {
     if (document.getElementById) {
      minutes = document.getElementById("minutes");
      seconds = document.getElementById("seconds");
      // if less than a minute remaining
      if (seconds < 59) {
       seconds.value = secs;
      } else {
       minutes.value = getminutes();
       seconds.value = getseconds();
      }
      secs--;
      setTimeout('Decrement()',1000);
      
     }
    }
    function getminutes() {
     // minutes is seconds divided by 60, rounded down
     mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
     return mins;
    }
    function getseconds() {
     // take mins remaining (as seconds) away from total seconds remaining
     return secs-Math.round(mins *60);
    }
    </script>
    
    <script>
    countdown();
    </script>
```

I want to stop this counter when it reaches to 0, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Just check remaining seconds, if they are not 0 you go on, otherwise you stop:

```
function Decrement() {
    ...

    if (secs !== 0) {
        secs--;
        setTimeout('Decrement()',1000);
    } else
        console.log('Timer stopped');
}
```

Here is a working fiddle:

```js
// set minutes
var mins = 1;
     
// calculate the seconds (don't change this! unless time progresses at a different speed for you...)
var secs = mins * 60;
    
function countdown() {
 setTimeout('Decrement()',1000);
}
    
function Decrement() {
 if (document.getElementById) {
   minutes = document.getElementById("minutes");
   seconds = document.getElementById("seconds");
   // if less than a minute remaining
   if (seconds < 59) {
    seconds.value = secs;
   } else {
    minutes.value = getminutes();
    seconds.value = getseconds();
   }
   if (secs !== 0) {
    secs--;
    setTimeout('Decrement()',1000);
   } else
      console.log('Timer stopped');
  }
}
    
function getminutes() {
  // minutes is seconds divided by 60, rounded down
  mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
  return mins;
}
    
function getseconds() {
  // take mins remaining (as seconds) away from total seconds remaining
  return secs-Math.round(mins *60);
}
    
countdown();
```

```html
<input id="minutes"/> : <input id="seconds"/>
```